# Android Management API enable service through policy

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, background-process

Is there a way to enable a service through policy? Or force an application to run in the background?

```
...
"applications":[{
        "installType":"FORCE_INSTALLED",
        "packageName":"XXXX"
}],
"permittedAccessibilityServices":{
         "packageNames": [
            "XXXX"
        ]
}
...
```